# Clojure replace a string with regex

Tags: regex, replace, clojure

Hello I want to replace a string in a file but in a special way.

For example I'm searching for a string like " hideMenu()" by using the regex #"\WhideMenu\W" so that it will not return some text where hideMenu is inside like "willHideMenu()".

Well I'm using the replace function like this:

```
(clojure.string/replace textFile #"\WhideMenu\W" "hideMenu2")
```

But the problem is that it now replaces the first whitespace and last character of the textfile too.

For example if there is:

```
function hideMenu()
```

it will be:

```
functionhideMenu2)
```

Which is pretty logical but how do I use replace without loosing the first and last character? I want as result:

```
function hideMenu2()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If clojure supports it, use lookahead and behind Regex:

```
(clojure.string/replace textFile #"(?<=\W)hideMenu(?=\W)" "hideMenu2")
```

otherwise you might need to match the character and use it in the replacement:

```
(clojure.string/replace textFile #"(\W)hideMenu(\W)" "$1hideMenu2$2")
```

Comment: the second solution looks like that it works real good for my problem.

Comment: @Kingalione Note that these two solutions won't work for `hideMenu` directly at the beginning or end of the file. It might be irrelevant for your specific use case but it's something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

`\W` matches non-word characters and `(` is one of them. What you probably want is a word-boundary match, expressed as `\b`:

```
(clojure.string/replace "hideMenu()" #"\bhideMenu\b" "hideMenu2")
;; => "hideMenu2()"
```

Comment: Another option is using capturing groups in the replacement. $0 is the whole of the capture, $1 the first capturing group, $2 the second etc. So `(clojure.string/replace "function hideMenu() " #"\b(hideMenu)\b" "$12"). => "function hideMenu2() "`.  In this case it might be irrelevant since boundaries aren't captured, but it might be worth mentioning.